# Python - Overlapping Ranges - Determine unique positions

Tags: python, list, range, bigdata, overlapping

I have a big dataset where each value is divided into 3 parts `[chromosome, start, end]`. What is the fastest way to calculate all the unique positions per chromosome, because I have a lot of overlap ranges.

So for example:
`[['chr1:10:60', 'chr1:5:70', 'chr3:50:80', 'chr1:54:90', 'chr1:120:180', 'chr3:50:90']]`

should result in:
`['chr1:5:90', 'chr1:120:180', 'chr3:50:90']`

I don't know if there even is an easy way to calculate this? But I figured out its worth the try to ask it here. Down here is a subset of my data.

Thanks in advance,

```
[['chr9:95149330:95149362', 'chr9:95149330:95149362', 'chr17:70386266:70386304', 'chr17:70386256:70386304', 'chr2:44672786:44672833', 'chr2:44672785:44672833', 'chr2:141966446:141966479', 'chr2:141966446:141966488', 'chr19:18126909:18126938', 'chr19:18126909:18127027', 'chr3:145082003:145082051', 'chr3:145082014:145082121', 'chr6:38835529:38835560', 'chr6:38835529:38835560', 'chr4:120372932:120372986', 'chr4:120372932:120372994', 'chr2:141014019:141014057', 'chr2:141014014:141014057', 'chr18:3445722:3445761', 'chr18:3445722:3445793', 'chr17:72329982:72330015', 'chr17:72329982:72330015', 'chr5:169911920:169911962', 'chr5:169911917:169911962', 'chr4:146482176:146482219', 'chr4:146482176:146482219', 'chr9:104285900:104285935', 'chr9:104285879:104285935', 'chr12:32941976:32942016', 'chr12:32941976:32942028', 'chrX:127923156:127923189', 'chrX:127923156:127923189', 'chr2:9535703:9535755', 'chr2:9535701:9535755', 'chr8:86476618:86476684', 'chr8:86476554:86476642', 'chr9:135756650:135756696', 'chr9:135756650:135756706', 'chr6:103004873:103004932', 'chr6:103004861:103004918', 'chr8:86476618:86476684', 'chr8:86476556:86476648', 'chr1:52280846:52280876', 'chr1:52280845:52280876', 'chr8:86476635:86476685', 'chr8:86476553:86476645', 'chr5:116046573:116046620', 'chr5:116046564:116046615', 'chrX:68039214:68039252', 'chrX:68039214:68039252', 'chr4:181491919:181491953', 'chr4:181491919:181491960', 'chr18:68050122:68050166', 'chr18:68050122:68050166', 'chr2:233985816:233985860', 'chr2:233985808:233985860', 'chr6:17020712:17020750', 'chr6:17020712:17020759', 'chr7:21950625:21950666', 'chr7:21950625:21950666', 'chr12:93292486:93292536', 'chr12:93292481:93292537', 'chr1:246515439:246515472', 'chr1:246515440:246515486', 'chr12:57084093:57084130', 'chr12:57084093:57084134', 'chr1:174801431:174801474', 'chr1:174801431:174801485', 'chr7:92499684:92499734', 'chr7:92499924:92499960', 'chr17:40328527:40328560', 'chr17:40328518:40328560', 'chr8:42944072:42944110', 'chr8:42944073:42944120', 'chr17:29890450:29890499']
```

Comment: Hmmm, it's not clear to me how you got from your example input data to your output.  Could you describe the algorithm in a little more detail?  Some code that does it (even inefficiently) would help me figure this out too.

Comment: @SamMussmann You should consider the numbers as lower and inclusive upper bounds for integer ranges and OP wants the non-redundant range limits per chromosome (chr)

Comment: One way might be: when you are going through the list, use a dictionary with chromosome as key, and a list of length 2 as value that keep track of the lowest and largest, and then, you go though the dictionary and reformat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with jonrsharpe about the general approach, but I think there's a more elegant way to do it.

First, we'll get the ranges for each chromosome (pretty much the same as jonrsharpe, although I like tuples better than lists for the ranges).

```
from collections import defaultdict

processed = defaultdict(list)

for s in data:
    chr_, start, end = s.split(":")
    processed[chr_].append((int(start), int(end)))
```

Now, we can make the merging much simpler by sorting the list for each chromosome by the start of the range.  This provides us with the nice property that if none of the previous ranges overlap with the current range, then we know that any merging we've done on the previous values is final and we won't have to go back to it.

```
for vals in processed.values():
    vals.sort()
    current = 1
    while current < len(vals):
      if vals[current-1][1] > vals[current][0]:
        # current and previous ranges overlap, so merge previous and current values.
        vals[current-1:current+1] = [(vals[current-1][0], vals[current][1])]
        # Because we reduced the number of values in the list by 1,
        # current now points at the next interesting value.
      else:
        current += 1 # We didn't merge, so we must increment current
```

Now we can put it back together as jonrsharpe does:

```
final = []
for key, vals in processed.items():
    for start, end in vals:
        final.append("%s:%s:%s" % (key, str(start), str(end)))
```

This also gives `final == ['chr3:50:90', 'chr1:5:90', 'chr1:120:180']`

Comment: Sorting certainly makes things a bit neater.

Comment: @Coryza: If you really want speed, I wouldn't use Python. :-) I expect this is close to the fastest you're going to get in Python, although you could get further gains by doing the merging in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in three steps:

1. Split out the ranges for each chromosome;
2. Extract the contiguous ranges; and
3. Assemble the outputs as required (`"chr:start:end"`).

Step one:

```
from collections import defaultdict

processed = defaultdict(list)

for s in data:
    chr_, pos = s.split(":", 1)
    processed[chr_].append(list(map(int, pos.split(":"))))
```

For

```
data == ['chr1:10:60', 'chr1:5:70', 'chr3:50:80', 
         'chr1:54:90', 'chr1:120:180', 'chr3:50:90']
```

this gives

```
processed == defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
                         {'chr3': [[50, 80], [50, 90]], 
                          'chr1': [[10, 60], [5, 70], [54, 90], [120, 180]]})
```

We can now group these together based on overlaps

```
for vals in processed.values():
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        finished = True
        for i, (s1, e1) in enumerate(vals):
            for s2, e2 in vals[i+1:]:
                if ((s2 <= s1 and e2 >= s1) or
                    (s2 <= e1 and e2 >= e1)):
                   vals[i][0] = min(s1, s2)
                   vals[i][1] = max(e1, e2)
                   vals.remove([s2, e2])
                   finished = False
```

Which gets us to:

```
processed == defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
                         {'chr3': [[50, 90]], 
                          'chr1': [[10, 90], [120, 180]]})
```

Now you can put it back together:

```
final = []
for key, vals in processed.items():
    for start, end in vals:
        final.append(":".join(map(str, (key, start, end))))
```

Which leaves:

```
final == ['chr3:50:90', 'chr1:10:90', 'chr1:120:180']
```

Comment: Think you lack the two cases where previous is encapsulated by current and vice versa? Also if you update an existing range and the updated now covers a previously not covered... is that really cared for too?

Comment: @deinonychusaur have fixed it for current encapsulating previous, but you are correct that the case e.g. `[(0, 10), (15, 25), (5, 20)]` would give `[(0, 20), (15, 25)]`, which is not the desired result... I will think about this.

Comment: I think it is actually easier/faster to check when they don't overlap and when two are merged one has to run over them all again. So for sake of speed I would guess do a first merge when adding and then iterate over until no more merges.

Comment: That seems like the most sensible approach

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe. Do you know a solution for the above mentioned problem? [["chrY", "1", "20"], ["chrY", "3", "17"], ["chrY", "15", "200"], ["chrY", "56", "87"], ["chrY", "54", "90"]] yields 1,90 and not 1,200